# pandas: export ndarray to csv

Tags: python, arrays, csv, pandas

I have a simple ndarray that I want to export to a csv, i.e. I just want a column of comma separated values. The reason is that I have to hand sort values from another df according to the values in the array. My data follows:

```
url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/108michael/ms_thesis/master/rgdpconc.csv'
result=pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)
uniq=result.IndustryClassification.unique()
#uniq.to_csv('rgdp_uniq_indstry_class.csv')
uniq   #this is my ndarray
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need create `DataFrame` and then write it [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'unique':uniq})
df.to_csv('rgdp_uniq_indstry_class.csv')
```

Or `Series` [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html):

```
s = pd.Series(uniq)
s.to_csv('rgdp_uniq_indstry_class.csv')
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Create the ndarray to a panda data frame and then use the `to_csv` pandas method.

```
uniq = pd.Dataframe({'var1':uniq})
uniq.to_csv('name_of_file')
```

The default separator is `','` but you can specify another one with the parameter sep like so

```
uniq.to_csv('name_of_file', sep =' ') #use whitespace for example
```

Also keep in mind the parameter `fmt` is very important if you are interested in preserving float precision. Eg.

```
uniq.to_csv('name_of_file', fmt='%1.3f')
```

Comment: `Series.unique()` returns a numpy array, so this won't work.

Comment: yes, sorry I was assuming the uniq variable was a dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You cannot give a ndarray object to_csv.Because they don't have such a method.So convert that to a pandas dataframe and give a csv output.

```
 import pandas as pd

 df = pd.DataFrame(uniq,columns=['suitable column name'])
 df.to_csv('path+csvfilename',index=False)  #### index=False will remove the extra index column in the csv
```